# latexmk not recording dependent files

Tags: latexmk, makefile

I don't know whether I don't understand the working of latexmk's `-deps` flag or it's not working as supposed.

I'm building a `Makefile` for typesetting several documents from a single `main.tex` file (I need different versions of the same document).
I want `make` to run `latexmk` if `main.tex` or any of the files it relies on changes. 
That can be achieved by manually indicating dependencies in the `Makefile`, but that's prone to errors and not reusable.

I found that `latexmk` has a `-deps` flag that can print a list of dependencies in the style of a `make` to include in your `Makefile`.
The issue is that it does not seem to record any files at all.
Whenever I run `latexmk` with the `-deps` flag I get an output like the one below, independent of how many other `.tex` files or images are included.

```
#===Dependents, and related info, for main.tex:
main.pdf :\
    main.tex
#===End dependents for main.tex:
```

So either `-deps` is not designed as I expect it to (recording all files necessary for building the final PDF) or there's something wrong with my `latexmk`.

Even if I copy the exact [`Makefile` example from the latexmk documentation](https://www.mankier.com/1/latexmk#ADVANCED_CONFIGURATION:_Some_extra_resources_and_advanced_tricks-Advanced_configuration:_Using_latexmk_with_make) it has the same behaviour.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of latexmk are you using? There was an error in versions 4.63b and 4.64 that produced the symptoms you see.  It was corrected in 4.64a. The current version is 4.65, and it produces correct dependency information.

Comment: @JohnCollins You're entirely correct, thank you! I had version 4.63b installed. I forgot to check since it was a days-old install of MacTeX, so I didn't expect outdated software. Updating to 4.65 solved the problem.